# TYPO3 - Using SQL operators in QueryBuilder API v8

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

How to use SQL operators (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_operators.asp) in this query? Like e.g. $uidMin = 5; $uidMax = 20; ...

```
$uid = 10;
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_content');
$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll();
$statement = $queryBuilder  
    ->select('uid', 'pid', 'header')            
    ->from('tt_content')
    ->where(
       $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', $uid)
    )           
    ->execute();    
while ($row = $statement->fetchAll()) {
    $this->view->assign('inet', $row);
}
```

What I tried is e.g (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

```
$uidMin = 5;
$uidMax = 20;
...
$queryBuilder->expr()->between('uid', $uidMin, $uidMax)
```

... but didn't work.

Comment: The between statement is pretty recent to the doctrine. Are you sure you're running on a version that supports it?

Comment: It seems that between() is not integrated yet: https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_query_1_1_expression_1_1_expression_builder.html in the 'ExpressionBuilder Class Reference'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works is this:

```
$queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('uid', $uidMin),
    $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('uid', $uidMax)
)
```

... but between() still doesn't work ...